# Title tag appears as not showing in a file within a subfolder

Tags: php, html

Title tag displayed as "untitled document" for a file(apparel.php) which is in a folder(fashion) but appears correctly for a file(login.php) which is not in a subfolder.
Here is the head section of apparel.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Apparel</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0,    
      initial-scale=1.0", user-scalable="yes" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.7/css    
     /bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/navbar.css"  />
     <script src="../js/navbar.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">    
     </script>
     <script src="../bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is the head section of login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Login </title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0,     
      initial-scale=1.0", user-scalable="yes" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css
      /bootstrap.min.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: the `<head>` should be fine. cleared the cache (strg + f5)?

Comment: Please open a private session in your browser or press `ctrl + r` to freshly reaload the page

Comment: I have just cleared the cache but the title is still "untitled document"

Comment: Well that's weird. Do you have any sort of post-script parsing handlers going on that may be replacing your `title` tag contents?

Comment: Marvin Fischer, I tried inPrivate browsing on my internet explorer but there is no change

Comment: You wouldn't by chance also have an `index.php` or `index.html` inside that `fashion/` subdirectory?

Comment: After a long time I discovered that the title becomes "untitled document" when I include geoplugin.class .php but when I exclude it the title is ok. Thanks for your help.